# selection of multiple columns with end(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing debug for a VBA template.
The Macro let users choose a excel file to import, then it will check each columns whether they correpond the requirements.
When I try to import a file, I alway get error "oveeflow" with the following line:

```
'maxRow = ws.Range(Cells(StartRow, AdditionalInfoColumns.OtherInfo).Address).End(xlDown).Row
```

My colleague tells me that I just need to add end(xlDown).End(xlup) like this:

```
maxRow = ws.Range(Cells(StartRow, AdditionalInfoColumns.OtherInfo).Address).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row
```

And it does work! I don't know why. So I try to do it in a simpler way as following:

```
maxRow = ws.Range(Cells(StartRow, 1).Address, Cells(StartRow, 3).Address).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row
```

It works as well.
Can someone please explain why does it work? Thank you for your answer.
PS: The value of xlDown and xlUp are -4121 and -4162.

Best Regards
Kai

Answer (score 2):

First of all `End(xlDown)` and `End(xlUp)` is nothing more than …

- `End(xlDown)` = Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow down</kbd>
- `End(xlUp)` = Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow up</kbd>

you can test this manually by selecting a range/cell and press the combination to see the effect on your actual worksheet.

The overflow error just comes because if you eg. select cell A1 in an empty worksheet and do `.End(xlDown)` it selects the very last cell of the worksheet. And if you now insert something it fails because the maximum rows of Excel are exceeded.

To find the last used row of a column it's better to use `End(xlUp)` instead of `End(xlDown)` eg:

```
LastUsedRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'finds the last used row in column A
```

Comment: Hi, PEH Thank you for your answer. Now I'm using the following code that works now:
maxRow = ws.Range(Cells(StartRow, 1).Address, Cells(StartRow, 3).Address).End(xlUp).Row
Now I figure out why End(xlDown) didn't work, because I've inserted rows which overflow the limit of excel, right?
But now I have another question, how could the following code work? Because my startRow is always 6 but End(XlUp) is row 1, right? 
Thank you for your help.
Best Regards.
Kai

Comment: @user4858867 Yes, therefore I suggest to use the `xlUp` method like in my answer to find the last used row.

Comment: Hi, PEH Thank you for your answer. Now I'm using the following code that works now: maxRow = ws.Range(Cells(StartRow, 1).Address, Cells(StartRow, 3).Address).End(xlUp).Row Now I figure out why End(xlDown) didn't work, because I've inserted rows which overflow the limit of excel, right? But now I have another question, how could the following code work? Because my startRow is always 6 but End(XlUp) is row 1, right? Thank you for your help. Best Regards. Kai

Comment: Well just test if `maxRow < startRow` like `If maxRow < startRow Then maxRow = startRow` to make sure `maxRow` is at least 6. • If your question is answered please mark it as solution.

Comment: I've wrote this and tested it 
If maxRow1 < StartRow Then MsgBox (True)

Comment: The result is alway true but I still don't understnad why does it work.

Comment: ① You use `maxRow1` instead of `maxRow`? why? ② Please be more specific, a message box does not fix your issue. Do exactly what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: Hello PEH, your code works. Thanks again. I find out that I can just use following code to get exact the last row which inludes value.
maxRow = ws.Range(Cells(StartRow, 1).Address, Cells(StartRow, 3).Address).End(xlUp).End(xlDown).Row

Answer (score 0):

End(xldown) has the same effect as pressing control and the down arrow (and End(xlright) is control and right arrow. If you try those key presses in a cell you will see it jumps to the next intersection of filled and empty cells (or the edge of the spreadsheet if there's no filled cells in the way)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.